# Ballerina support for reactive programming

Tags: ballerina

Are there any plans to add reactive programming support to the ballerina platform?

I checked the docs and I see async operations return futures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see Ballerina supporting reactive style of programming because with Ballerina's lightweight threads and non-blocking IO capabilities, one can write straight-forward imperative code and expect Ballerina runtime to take care of concurrency (and performance) aspects.

Disclaimer: I don't have extensive experience with reactive programming other than reading up some tutorials/articles and trying stuff. So I might be missing some advantages of reactive programming here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I went back and read more about non-blocking IO and lightweight threads support in ballerina and I have a better view.

Found this interesting post - https://medium.com/@lafernando/ballerina-concurrency-done-right-fa0afa350cb0
plus the official docs https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/fork.html and https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/workers.html

Comment: Happy to be helpful, Ballerina also support async function invocation https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/async.html this is similar to workers.